# Powershell | get a value from 2 nested invoke commands

Tags: powershell, textbox, invoke

i want to transfer the values from the invoke commands to local. I have problems to get the values from the second invoke command. I want $computers and $tasks in the textbox. Any Ideas? I have tried with return but then i can only get the values from first invoke command.

EDITED:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remote -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

### get all computers in Domain ###
$computers = dsquery computer "DC=kanzlei,DC=local" -o rdn
Write-Host ("In dieser Domäne gibt es die folgenden Server:")
write-host $computers

#configure all computers
foreach($computer in $computers) {

    $session3 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remote -Credential $cred_session

    Invoke-Command -Session $session3 -ScriptBlock {
    write-host "Tasks for $env:computername gonna be activated"

    #### acitivate tasks #### 
    $tasks = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\RA-MICRO_Update_Routine\" | Enable-ScheduledTask | FL Taskname,State }
    write-host "$tasks"
    }
      }
}

  ##### I want vriable $Computers and $Tasks here on Local ####
   do anything with $tasks 
   do anything with $computers
```

Comment: I can not tell what exactly you’re trying to do but I know you’re going to have double hop and variable scoping issues

Comment: also can you isolate the problematic part and be more specific in what you mean by "I have problems" !?

Comment: my fuction write the output to an texbox but in the invoke command i cant get the output i know i have to do it with scope but i dont know how

Comment: so i want $computers in the textbox and i want $tasks in the textbox

Comment: Can you update your code sample so other people can just cut&paste it locally to reproduce your issue. For example I can see a variable called ```$OutBox``` in your ```To-Outbox``` function but it's not initialised anywhere in your code samples so I don't know what it is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a question that is more likely to get an answer. - particularly the "Help others reproduce the problem" section.

Comment: i just want to pass the remote variable to local

Comment: so i edit my code maybe is more clear for you to understand

Comment: [1] why the sessions? `Invoke-Command` has a parameter called `-ComputerName` that can take an array of computer names. [2] You create new sessions, but never do [Remove-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession) [3] Simply have each computer output an **object** with both its computername and tasks. Then capture that at the start of the foreach loop

Comment: I connect via vpn to the network  and get the computer names with the first session from there i open the next session to activat the task remotely sorry for my English :-)